# Building a dynamic library, and linking other dynamic libraries on which it depends

Tags: c, gcc, cross-platform, ld, dynamic-linking

Context: I'm doing cross-platform development. I'm building a dynamic `.so/.dylib/.dll` library, itself dependent on other `.so/.dylib/.dll` libraries. These libraries can be multiple versions of the same dependency as we develop (some are standard, like openssl, others are not; others are even open-source-but-proprietary, so linking them statically is not allowed in production). So to not mess up other things on my machine(s), and allow collaborative development with git, I keep my libraries "locally" in the git repo's folder, rather than in `/usr/local/lib` or one of the other such directories at the root. I keep these binary dependencies in their own directory substructure, and copy the right dependency into the build directory when building for a specific platform/build.

At this point:

- linking all dependencies (compiled with -fPIC, etc) statically into the final dynamic library works fine on all platforms;
- for fully dynamic dependencies, Windows causes no issues, since just copying dlls around gets the job done;
- for fully dynamic dependencies on Linux and Max, I have for now been incapable of ever building a dynamic library that can find these local dynamic libraries on its own.

I've tried basically every possible syntax of `-Wl,-rpath` etc. to no avail. `ldd` always returns "not found" for these dependencies. I have become quite proficient with Mac's `install_name_tool` and Linux's `patchelf`, but this feels like a very poor workaround (even when I automate their use in our Makefile); it's wordy, and it seems to me like there must be a better way.

**What is the correct way to build such a dynamic library, dependent on other dynamic libraries, which themselves tend to be in a custom location, and moved around ?**

(Also note that for a `make install` we also move everything to the root and use patchelf/install_name_tool to look for existing versions of our dependencies on the user's machine. If there's a more standard way to do things, please, do tell.)

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried basically every possible syntax

That is unlikely to be true. It's also impossible to guess what you have and have not tried.

For Linux in particular, you are probably looking for:

```
gcc -shared foo.o ... -o libfoo.so -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/' -L... -lbar -lbaz
```

If `libbar.so` and `libbaz.so` are located at runtime in the same directory as `libfoo.so`, then `libfoo.so` should find them there.

Note: you *must* use single quotes around `$ORIGIN` to prevent shell expansion.

Comment: I've tried this syntax. But what you say about shell expansion might actually be a lead. I do all my compilation from a Makefile, where the $ is a reserved symbol. Would you have any warnings/advice for that ?